# iOS Facebook Login Fast-App Switch Stays on Facebook App

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'll preface this by saying that this bug is difficult to reproduce and I have not been able to find a pattern for when it occurs.

When a user selects the Facebook login option in my iOS app, the app fast-switches to the Facebook app, and will stay in the Facebook app on the News Feed. Then when a user returns to my iOS app, and attempt to Facebook login again, it will fast-app switch and the login will continue as intended. When this bug occurs, it always fails, and then works reliably on the following attempt.

Comment: can you please post the code here which you are using to login through facebook

Comment: which sdk version are you using? I'm having the same issue on 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "fbXXXXXXXXXX:" in your plist

XXXXXX = you app id

When the app switches back it needs to know where to go, your app needs to respond to the url correctly.